# Virtual drawing pad using color detection in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to make a virtual drawing pad by detecting and tracking red objects in a video from a webcam and increasing corresponding intensity values on a blank background.
I am using this code to track red objects

```
data = getsnapshot(vid);
diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));  %find red regions in image

diff_im = medfilt2(diff_im, [3 3]);               %Use a median filter to filter out noise

diff_im = im2bw(diff_im,0.18);      % Convert the resulting grayscale image into a binary image.


diff_im = bwareaopen(diff_im,300);    % Remove all those pixels less than 300px,

[bw, count]  = bwlabel(diff_im, 8);

if(count > 0)
%% then draw rectangle around centroid of detected object
```

I am checking for every pixel, which increases processing time when image size increases(even for 640*480). As a result of this output is blank for many frames. How can I improve it..??

Comment: Why do you need to increase image size? If you are looking for an object at least 300px size, you can do it in small size as well. Use `imresize` to work on a small scale image.

Comment: 1. Can you upload an example? 2. is the camera stationary? can you remove the background?

Comment: @Shai,i tried to capture low resolution images and then increase their size but result became worse and it is very sensitive to light how can I resolve this issue...??